# Check if ActiveRecord::Relation alread includes JOIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm inside method that adds filter (user.type) to my query/relation.

Sometimes if grouping by the user (which needs INNER join to `users table` in another module) is selected before filtering I receive an error:

`PostgreSQL: PG::DuplicateAlias: ERROR: table name "users" specified more than once`

Before error happen JOIN is already in query -

```
$ pry> relation.to_sql
SELECT \"posts\".* FROM \"posts\"
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id
WHERE \"posts\".\"created_at\" BETWEEN '2019-05-01 00:00:00'
AND '2020-05-01 23:59:59' AND \"users\".\"type\" = 'Guest'"
```

I wanna fix it, by checking if the table is already joined inside my ActiveRecord::Relation object. I added:

```
def join_users
  return relation if /JOIN users/.match? relation.to_sql

  relation.joins('LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id')
end
```

This solution works, but I wonder - is there any better way to check if JOIN is inside relation?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you can use `joins_values`, which isn't documented, but is an `ActiveRecord_Relation` public method that returns an array containing the name of the table the current query (object) is constructed with:

```
Post.joins(:user).joins_values # [:user]
Post.all.joins_values          # []
```

Comment: TIL there is also a `.includes_values` method

Answer (score 1):

if simple join

```
 Post.joins(:user)
```

you can find via `joins_values`

so it will look like `Post.joins(:user).joins_values # [:user]`

if post has **left joins**

```
Post.left_joins(:user)
```

you can find via `left_outer_joins_values`

So in this case if you write `Post.joins(:user).joins_values # []`
so you can fix it by writing  `Post.joins(:user).left_outer_joins_values # [:user]`